# How to detect when BarChart finishes rendering in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, bar-chart

Is there a way to detect when a BarChart finishes rendering?  I am trying to add a snapshot of the BarChart to a PDF file but before doing this I need to wait until the BarChart has finished loading.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to the updateComplete event : http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html#event:updateComplete